# How to know what program uses which bandwith.

Tags: windows-7, security, internet

From few days my Internet connection is being used by some application internally by my system.

> 1. I want to know which application is using it? I used Task Manager to see which resource is using my network it just say svchost.exe
>      (which is internally running more services, processes can't figured it
>      through it)
> 2. Can I restrict my Internet access to only certain applications (I think you are gonna say `firewall`, i even tried it but it is making
>      my system damn slow, i have an Intel i7 with 8GB RAM, so i uninstalled
>      it)
> 3. And this usage of Internet making CPU usage more than 15% which make my PC hotter. In turn makes my fan runs fast which in turn makes
>      sound. Immediatly after disconnecting my Internet my CPU usage will go
>      normal (1 or 2 % mostly even with lot of apps opened)

Comment: Maybe [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) might help.

Comment: thats what i mentioned in my question think it was edited. it just says svchost.exe( and some other apps like chrome which indeed i know its presence and its usage) which is a bunch of services.

Comment: And i usually get NSIS error pop up. And then immediatly my network usage will comes to its regular position(which i can find a reason which app is using my net)

Comment: Try to understand the answer I gave and the one this one is duplicate. If you deem it useful, try to accept it.
On this last comment I suggest opening another question, or, better yet, **try to search the Internet**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful about asking too much questions on a single post.

With this being said, I'll try to answer this by item.

1. Try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Or Search The Internet. [link](http://www.pcworld.com/article/241664/how_to_monitor_your_bandwidth.html) [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43713/how-to-monitor-the-bandwidth-consumption-of-individual-applications/)
2. I **am** going to say Firewall. It is **The Right Thing To Do**. It shouldn't make your system slow, even because Windows has an integrated firewall. You didn't say the name of the firewall program you used, but if you want to disable Internet access to some programs, you can set up this on Windows Firewall, with no extra overhead on your system.
3. Maybe it isn't the Internet's fault, maybe it's **Windows Update** or some other application that needs Internet access to run. Your CPU is always running at 100%. I'm not going to delve myself in technical details but it is. If your problem is the fan making noise try living with a desktop enclosed by wood panels ;P. The fans are probably just trying to cool of the CPU or GPU, and isn't something you could control easily.

Comment: i installed comodo firewall. after installing it suddenly every event(opening any app,even comodo firewall will be done after a minute or more) i didn't see any processing thing happening between me clicking any app and its opening but its just takes tooo long to open.

Comment: Strange, and for the question you asked, off-topic of me to try and debug that behaviour. Recommend using either Windows Firewall (that can do what you propose on 2.) or other firewall. I, personally, am happy with Windows Firewall. I did use Zone Alarm's firewall at one time but I deemed it too intrusive. Also, be aware of the [duplicate] nature of the post and, in general, try to **write well**.

Comment: And internet usage is not my issue. your first link it just give network usage which i have got already. i want an app which tells me which application is using my internet bandwidth.

Comment: no my CPU isn't running 100%. not even once. my problem is not fan sound. fan sound for a known reason is acceptable and if fan sound  with unknown reason annoys me(mostly anyone) if got a reason to fan sound our mind will override it and don't care about it and will continue our work. actually CPU usage is my problem that is happening only due to internet usage. immediatly after disconnecting my internet my CPU usage will come normal.

Comment: i will try to write well. we must accept born baby wont walk. if it borns in a world people walks does'nt mean to walk immedialtly. and i said i will try to write it well. thank you.

Comment: OK. First thing - be polite. We're only trying to help you. Second. Process Explorer and NetBalancer (2nd link) does show how each application uses network bandwith.
Third, trust me on that CPU is always running at 100%, for too technical reasons. If you don't believe me check Task Manager. If you want more detailed answers search the Net or make a more detailed question.

Comment: i dont know where i sounds rude. but if i did my apologies. i know you are assisting me. and i really appreciate it. what i am trying to say is my issue is not about knowing my internet usage(like how upload bytes or how many download bytes). i want to know which application in my system is currently using my internet like its automatically updating by itself or any virus file getting my bandwidth or some thing wierd like america is getting my data by placing virus in my PC(jus for fun, you know how much real it is, off topic)

Comment: Please read the answer I gave you. If that doesn't help you, learn to read English. That is all.

Comment: And one thing you said that CPU is always running 100% and you said to check in task manager but when i checked it says 4% and its going up and down a point or two. can you tell me how? i think it can't be 100% always.